Free energies with generalized entropic contributions
In equilibrium thermodynamics, one encounters the (Gibbs) free energy, defined for some random variable $X$,
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:G}
G(X) = E_X[U] - \beta^{-1}H(X) 
\end{equation}
where $U$ is some potential function and $H$ is the (Shannon) entropy of $X$. When $U$ is well behaved enough and $X$ has density $f_X$, it's known that $f_X \propto \exp(-\beta U(x))$ minimizes $G$. There is also a relationship to the Fokker-Planck equation, which is the "Wasserstein gradient flow" of $G$.
Is there a situation where one naturally encounters generalizations of $G$ of the form
$$
G(X) = E_X[U] - \beta^{-1}H(Y)
$$
where the entropic contribution is from some other variable $Y = h(X)$, for (possibly non-invertible) $h$?
In physical words, viewing the minimization of $G$ as minimization of $U$ at fixed "temperature" $\beta^{-1}$ or maximization of entropy at fixed "energy" $U$, does one encounter situations where the "temperature" (entropic contribution) is defined in terms of other coordinates than the energetic one?
